# status bar and Navigation bar problem after dismissed modal view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, modalviewcontroller, overlapping

the apps launched the mailcomposer modal view (MFMailComposeViewController) when the Contact Us button is pressed.
but once the modal view is loaded, the status bar is hidden automatically.

I setStatusBarHidden Status to NO after modal view controller is dismissed.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

but the status bar and navigation bar is overlapped after ModalViewController is dismissed.

I got no clue how to fix it. 
Appreciate any kind help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem is solved by launching the MFMailComposeViewController from appDelegate tabBarController

```
 myAppDelegate *mDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[mDelegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

instead of launching from the navigation Controller

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```