# iOS7 hide status bar but not adjust top layout guide

Tags: xcode, ios7, interface-builder, autolayout, statusbar

I deal with autolayout set up in Interface Builder. I want to not offset views that are pinned to top layout guide when I hide status bar in runtime.

I have discovered that `myViewController.topLayoutGuide.length` changes from 20 to 0 when hiding status bar. How to prevent it? Or (as workaround) how to set up fullscreen view for various window sizes without pin to top layout guide?

Some code to describe my situation:

```
Log(@"frame: %@, top: %.0f", NSStringFromCGRect(myViewController.myView.frame), self.topLayoutGuide.length);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
Log(@"frame: %@, top: %.0f", NSStringFromCGRect(myViewController.myView.frame), self.topLayoutGuide.length);
```

Output:

```
frame: {{40, 24}, {240, 40}}, top: 20
frame: {{40, 4}, {240, 40}}, top: 0
```

Comment: Not totally clear on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to have the view show the elements at a fixed location, no matter if the status bar is showing or not? Or is this an iOS6/7 switching issue? You can also hide the status bar in IB if that is causing problems when you lay out components vs runtime result.

Comment: I hide status bar in runtime and at that moment UI shifts. The reason is in `topLayoutGuide`. I want to keep UI at its position when status bar hides.

Comment: Are you showing the view and -then- getting rid of the status bar, or are you telling the status bar not to appear before showing the view?

Comment: I'm afraid we are talking about different things...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The topLayoutGuide property is readonly and you can't prevent it from changing.

You can pin your items not to the topLayoutGuide but to the superview. That should resolve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :-) The superview constraint seems to be only available if done via the same menu on your screenshot.

Comment: This is a fantastic tip!

Comment: Great! you save my time ~

Comment: Also you need to set Navigation Bar translucent option to TRUE.